# Javascript clearInterval() not working, how do i stop setInterval()?

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

The loop starts fine on mouseover, but it doesn't stop on mouseout!
What am i doing wrong?

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function iniciarep(x) {
        var iddointervalo = setInterval(function(){ change(x); }, 500);
        }
        function terminarep() {
        clearInterval(iddointervalo);
        }
        function change(x) { 

**do stuff here (working fine)**

        }  
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="c3" src="letras/m1.svg" alt="m"  onmouseover='iniciarep(this);' onmouseout='terminarep();'>
```

Comment: Your variable `iddointervalo` only exists within the scope of `iniciarep`...

Comment: scope error, you only define your `idointervalo` inside your funciton, you cannot access it from inside `terminarep` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a global variable, because the local one is not known later.

```
var iddointervalo;

function iniciarep(x) {
    iddointervalo = setInterval(function(){ change(x); }, 500);
}

function terminarep() {
    clearInterval(iddointervalo);
}
```